# How to set React initial state based on radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So I have a sibling component whose state is influenced by the radio button

```
constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: "option1",
      bgColor: '',
    }
  }
  handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value,
      bgColor: changeEvent.target.name
    });
  };
  

  render() {
      return (
      <div>
      <CardBack fill={this.state.bgColor}/>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
          type="radio"
          name="blue"
          value="option1"
          checked={this.state.selectedOption === "option1"}
          onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
          />
          Option 1
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
          type="radio"
          name="red"
          value="option2"
          checked={this.state.selectedOption === "option2"}
          onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
          />
          Option 2
        </label>
      </div>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

I want to make it so that the initial state is whatever color selected through Option 1. In this case blue. I know there's a way to do that, but right now I'm not getting it (I'm getting black, which is the original color of the svg fill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the state of the Component based on the input name within this Component before actually rendering it. The best option to proceed is to set the initial state to "blue"/"red" depending on what you want to choose first ("blue" in your case)

```js
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    const componentValue = document.querySelector("input[name=blue]");
    console.log(componentValue) // will evaluate to null
    
    class ComponentName extends Component {
      constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          selectedOption: "option1",
          bgColor: document.querySelector("input[name=blue]"),
        }
        console.log(this.state.bgColor)// will evaluate to null
      }

      handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
        const componentValue = document.querySelector("input[name=blue]").name;
        console.log(componentValue); // will evaluate to "blue"
        this.setState({
          selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value,
          bgColor: changeEvent.target.name
        });
      };

      render({
        ...
      )}
    }
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I was going to do just wondering if there was an easier way. Tbh I should probably change the UI so that the radio buttons are unselected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting your question right, but you can simply set `bgColor` to `blue`:

```
constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: "option1",
      bgColor: 'blue',
    } 
}
```